# SQL Server Logging Denied Access

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, event-log, auditing

I was wondering if anyone knew if the logging capabilities of SQL Server extended to tracking user attempts to query information on which they do not have access.  For example, if a user attempts to query an object or schema on which he lacks permissions, the logs capture the attempt when he receives an error similar to below:

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure SProc, Line 1
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'SProc', database 'DB', schema 'SCHEMA'.
```

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There is an event called `User Error Message` under `Errors and Warnings` section.
You can log that event

Comment: Thank you but I'm not familiar with that feature, I think that may have been version 2005 or before. I'm running 2008r2 at the moment.